# How to assign random session key to visitor who visit the website in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, session, cart

I have not much experience in PHP. i am creating a shopping store in PHP where a visitor can add item into cart without creating account (as guest). so i just want to assign him a unique id or key for add to cart process. so how can i assign him a random key when he visit the website?

Comment: [Php Seesions](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) might help you understand how to deal with php sessions, and what PHP session is

Comment: use session variables

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: What would you need any such key for? You just start the session, and put the data into the session.

Comment: i know about the sessions but i can't figure out that how to assign random session key to visitor?

Comment: [session_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start) does pretty much everything for you in this field. You probably want to know How to get the key that was generated by `sessio_start()`. Otherwise, you don't really have to save it.

Comment: Why do you think you would _need_ any such “random key”? What for? The session is specific to the current visitor of your site already, _by definition_.

Comment: @CBroe i need to get random key so the visitor can add items into cart as guest. and for this i need a unique key which i can assign to visitor when he add a item in his cart.

Comment: That still doesn’t make sense. What would this key actually be needed _for_? Again, the session already _is_ unique to the current visitor of your site.

Comment: the session with already be assigning a GUID to the user anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**another approach**: PHP already creates a unique id for each session, this is how sessions work.  You could use this to identify the user.

You can get this from the session with `session_id()`.

You can also set a session id with this, but please read the first comment on the [document page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php)

Answer (score 2):

```php
// Start session
session_start();

// Assign a unique key
$_SESSION['USER_SESSION_KEY'] = uniqid('myPrefix', true);
```

I would advise to build this into some sort of a function, to make sure that if the key was already assigned then you should try to generate again for maximum uniqueness. Store the key in a database to keep track of already generated keys.

For more information on how uniqid works [click here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)